# Sidekiq Upstart on AmazonLinux 2018.03

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, sidekiq, upstart, amazon-linux

My goal is to add the sidekiq service to upstart on AmazonLinux 2018.03.

Since I want to upgrade sidekiq to version 6, There are needs to manage the process by OS like upstart.

I put a file to `/etc/init/sidekiq.conf` from [here](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/master/examples/upstart/sidekiq.conf).

After that, `initctl list | grep sidekiq` command shows nothing, so I tried `sudo initctl reload-configuration`, but nothing changed.

`status sidekiq` command shows `status: Unknown job: sidekiq`.

What else do I need to do to add the sidekiq service to upstart?

Comment: never worked with sidekiq but usually in order to start any service in Linux its s1ystemctl start service name` and to make it persistent on reboot `systemctl enable service name` in your case if you configured everything then final steps should be `sudo systemctl enable sidekiq 
sudo systemctl start sidekiq `

Comment: Unfortunately AmazonLinux 2018.03 does not support systemd, so I use upstart.

Comment: can you use this `service sidekiq start`

Comment: The ‘service’ is the command of SystemV Init. I’m talking about Upstart, sorry.